# Display the taskbar clock on multiple screens in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8, taskbar, clock

Is it possible to display the clock on the taskbar on each screen in Windows 8, preferably without 3rd-party tools?

Comment: @Karan I'm speaking of the taskbar.

Comment: Ah, read only the title and thought you were talking of the desktop and start screen. Anyway, is the query really specific to Windows 8 or equally valid for older versions as well that supported multi-monitor setups?

Comment: By default Windows 8 is configured to show taskbar on all monitors (see Taskbar Properties dialog box). Isn't the clock displayed too?

Comment: Although this is NOT at the taskbar, it could be helpful to some (eg. running fullscreen apps on one monitor and want clock on another): Install a "Clock" app via the Windows Store. Run the clock and move it to the other screen by pressing Windows logo key + PgUp/PgDown

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows 10 Anniversary Update (version 1607, build 14393.10) was pushed to standard update channels on August 2 2016, and now there is no longer any need to install third party software to use dual monitor taskbar clocks.

[image]

This screenshot of a dual-monitor setup shows the clock on both the left and the right monitor taskbars outlined in red. No additional configuration is required (other than allowing the install of the update).

Comment: And how did you activate this?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler This is activated by default upon installation of Windows 10 version 1607.

Comment: Hm, I still have build 1511, but Windows claims there are no updates. Maybe my domain has not (yet) allowed for it... Or [_If you have already deployed Windows 10 and use Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) and/or System Center Configuration Manager servicing plans, you can get the Windows 10, version 1607 update on August 16th._](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2016/08/03/windows-10-anniversary-update-servicing.aspx)

Comment: Well, until then [T-Clock](https://superuser.com/questions/495201/display-the-taskbar-clock-on-multiple-screens-in-windows#comment1531375_603167) does the trick. Or even better, due to its customization options.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I also realized I was still on 1511. I found out it was because I had "Defer Upgrades" checked in my Windows Update settings. I thought this meant to defer them until it asked for my permission, but the actually means it will defer major releases "for several months" if it is checked and not even notify you or ask you about the release. I unchecked it, immediately checked for updates, and it downloaded the 1607 update.

Comment: Question now is.... How do you remove it?

Comment: @Lars - **You cannot.**  The registry key that determine if the new clock behavior was used or not was removed when the build it was introduced in ( 14393 ) was released as Version 1607.

Answer (score 76):

You can't display the clock on both taskbar. It is possible to drag your primary taskbar to the second monitor providing they are unlocked first.

Comment: As of the Windows 10 Anniversary Update this answer will no longer be correct - as multiple clocks per taskbar will be supported

Comment: @RoguePlanetoid Will it just be a matter of right-clicking the taskbar, selecting properties, and finding it right on the Taskbar tab?

Comment: The answer will remain correct - the question explicitly covers windows 8

Comment: Perfect answer. 1. It's not possible 2. Dragging unlocked taskbar as needed whenever you want does the job

Answer (score 43):

I wanted the same thing you were looking for.  I just discovered if you hit <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> , this seems to bring the time and date to the lower left of the screen wherever you are. It helps me, and I hope it is helpful to others.

Comment: Doesn't work ingame though, that's the only reason I want a 2nd clock.

Comment: Does nothing for me on windows 10

Answer (score 13):

#### Third-Party Solutions

- [Ultramon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) - ($$ but 30-day free trial period) mentioned by @Robert Kelly
- [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/) - Only the Pro versions ($$ but 30-day free trial period) show the clock on all taskbars.  Free version does not.
- [Actual Multiple Monitors](http://www.actualtools.com/multiplemonitors/) - 30-day free trial period
- [MultiMon](http://www.mediachance.com/free/multimon.htm) - Lighter weight version of zbar and ultramon, and easier to set up.  Free version designed for XP.  Paid versions have not been updated recently (no info on Win8+ support).
- [T-Clock Redux](https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock) - Free and open source (GitHub - pre-compiled binaries are available).

Finally, not a taskbar clock per se, but [DexClock](http://dexpot.de/dexclock.php?id=dexclock) is an interesting (free) wallpaper-based clock solution that might address your needs.

Comment: DisplayFusion was cool but didn't' like that it wasn't free. I ended up going with a simplistic one called DS Clock which is simplistic and has a low memory footprint. I have it looking pretty vanilla even though it's not exactly the same it gets the job done :)

Comment: Ultramon also has a free trial period.

Comment: None of these freely get the job done

Comment: @Baodad, Can you add Third-Party solution 'T-Clock' to your post?https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock

Comment: @mathijsuitmegen You should have posted that as a separate answer, it's the only free alternative and it works perfectly even with Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

Possible with a program called Ultramon. [Link](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/)

Of course, this is WITH 3rd party tools, but it looks completely native once you get it setup. Just if you're still looking for a solution! Good luck.

Comment: It's not free, sadly :(

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is currently not possible without a 3rd party utility.

Answer (score 0):

For win7 there is an open-source tool: https://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmonitortb

It's a little bit unstable, but it does the job perfectly