# Displaying time in taskbar on all monitors

Tags: windows-8

Given two-monitor setup and Windows 8 native support for such setup, is there an easy way to show current time/date in taskbar on **both** monitors?

Currently, Windows 8 displays time on primary monitor only:

[image: time/date]

Comment: Duplicate question:
http://superuser.com/questions/495201/display-the-clock-on-multiple-screens-in-windows-8/603167

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know how is by using [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/). It allows you to have multi-monitor taskbars and you can customize them individually.