# How to put the taskbar's notification area on two screens in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, display, taskbar

I have two screens on my Windows 8.1 computer (with Classic Shell Start Menu installed). The thing is that I would like to have the taskbar's [notification area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa511448.aspx) (where the clock and all the icons like Skype or Spotify are, at the right) on both of my screens, and not only on the primary one.

Could you help me ? I would like not to install a heavy and paid software like DisplayFusion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display the clock on multiple screens in Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/495201/display-the-clock-on-multiple-screens-in-windows-8)

Comment: Currently, you can't do it without 3rd party software.

Comment: Do you have one which is not heavy and paid ? ^^'

Comment: Nope, if there was one someone knew about, it'd probably have been added as an answer to that existing question by now. :)

Comment: How about Dual Monitor Taskbar? http://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmonitortb/ GPLv3. Customizable. But untested in Win 8, so YMMV.

Comment: It's working, thanks, but there is all the useless Windows icons (like network, sound, the maintenance center...), there is not the pinned softwares and, the most annoying, when you right-click an icon on the systray you can't dismiss the popup menu without clicking on it...

Comment: Did you right click on the bar and then select "Properties" and try changing the settings there?

Comment: Yes I did, but there is not a lot of options available unfortunately...

Answer (score 2):

The free version of [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/) will give you a taskbar on each screen and allow you to toggle the system tray, clock, start button, and app tabs on/off for each monitor independently.
[image]

Comment: It works better, the only weird thing is the appearance of the Classic Shell button, it's... big xD

Comment: **Avoid** installing DisplayFusion what P Fitz recommended, it disables features what comes with Windows by default when you install the free version. You could say it's more or less taking your computer hostage until you either pay them for the Pro version or re-install Windows 8.

Comment: I do support and testing for DisplayFusion and just wanted to clarify a couple of things here. The multi-monitor taskbar is only available in the Pro version of DisplayFusion, but it is available to test in the 30-day trial.

I'm not sure what user2179979 is referring to when he says it disable features that come with Windows 8. It will disable the built-in Windows 8 taskbars if you enable the DisplayFusion taskbars (though it prompts first), and if you no longer use DisplayFusion, they can easily be re-enabled through the taskbar properties.