# How can I show the System Tray across multiple monitors in Windows 8.1

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, notification-area

In Windows 8.1, the taskbar is shared between all 3 of my monitors but the System Tray only shows up on my monitor that is noted as my "Main Display" in Screen Resolution settings.

Is there a way I can have the system tray show up on all of my monitors?

**Edits:**
I noticed this guy asked a similar question about the clock, so I doubt I'll get any different answers.
[Display the taskbar clock on multiple screens in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/495201/display-the-clock-on-multiple-screens-in-windows-8)

Comment: If its possible;  It would require third-party software;  What has your research shown?

Comment: I remember this used to be possible in Windows 8. Ideally, I would avoid 3rd party software, but it appears to be the only option. This guy asked a similar question about the clock. http://superuser.com/questions/495201/display-the-clock-on-multiple-screens-in-windows-8

Comment: You will indeed need third-party software.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put the taskbar's notification area on two screens in Windows 8.1](http://superuser.com/questions/733913/how-to-put-the-taskbars-notification-area-on-two-screens-in-windows-8-1), [Display the clock on multiple screens in Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/495201/display-the-clock-on-multiple-screens-in-windows-8)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Display fusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/) for a couple years now. It is well integrated with Windows 7/8/8.1 and adds many features that I didn't realise I wanted until I used them (e.g. window position snapping).

It even has the clock on the extended monitor.