# Putting notification tray on multiple screens

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, notification-area

When I am using multiple screens with Windows 10 is it possible to get the notification tray to display on both screens in extended display mode? For example like this

[image]

Instead of this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a native way to do that within Windows 10.  There is [third-party software](https://superuser.com/questions/733913/how-to-put-the-taskbars-notification-area-on-two-screens-in-windows-8-1) you can purchase to reach that goal, so it depends upon how much you value that functionality.

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks for the answer. I will look into it.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: Unfortunately, I had no luck. Whilst display fusion would work I don't really want to pay for this feature. I will just write my own little program to do this when I get time to. If you're interested I will post it below when I finish it

Comment: That is unfortunate, but your sentiment is understandable.  If you do write something yourself, I am sure that the Super User community would enjoy seeing it and you could flag your own answer as the official solution!