# Windows 10 - Put Clock and Audio Icon on All Monitors

Tags: windows-10

With Windows 10, is it possible to have the clock and Volume-Adjust-Icon on all monitors in a multi-monitor setup?

Comment: Would showing the entire taskbar on all monitors be suitable for your requirement?

Comment: Yes, as long as each taskbar is complete with clock and everything you'd expect to see if you had only one monitor, but on all monitors.

Comment: Found a potential [duplicate question](http://superuser.com/questions/495201/display-the-clock-on-multiple-screens-in-windows-8) - aimed at Windows 8 though, not sure if anything has changed in Windows 10 in this regard.

Comment: You could also look at [this](http://lynxnzl.deviantart.com/art/Windows-Taskbar-Clock-for-dual-monitor-setups-551582226) but it will require third party software, and only seems to include the clock, not the other notification icons.

Comment: @LonnieBest  - With Version 1607 its possible to display the clock on multiple monitors (happens by default) but the taskbar icons only appear on the primary monitor.  If you want that functionality the only way to do that is third-party software.

Comment: I guess I'll stick with [Ubuntu 16.04.4](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop), which does this by default. Thanks Ramhound.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of Windows 10 version 1803 this still seems **not possible**. The *clock* will now by default display on all monitors, but the *notification icons* (such as the volume control mentioned in the question) only show on your "Main Display".

The only options currently available are (a) switching your "Main Display", or (b) using third party software.

Comment: Could you recommend a third party software that offers this option?

Comment: @Swen I recommend asking a question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ended up here because my setup requires my least-visible monitor to me the primary, because its a touch screen and the touch input ***gets applied to the main display*** (setting any other monitor as primary means that touch input is relative to that display; i.e. impossible to use). :(

Comment: Now that 1903 is out, has this become possible?

Comment: @LonnieBest No.

Comment: Still not possible on 20H1, slow ring.

Comment: Is it now possible in Windows 11? [Ubuntu Unity](https://ubuntuunity.org/) allows it.

Answer (score 6):

Although I have been unable to show the system tray on all monitors, you are able to move the main taskbar and system tray to another monitor. You must unlock the taskbar and then drag it over to the monitor you want it displayed on.

Answer (score -3):

we could show taskbar on all monitor. So that you could see the clock and use volume on multiple monitor.
I referred link: 
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3899-hide-show-taskbar-multiple-displays-windows-10-a.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUH0m.png)

Comment: Welcome to Super User!, your could solve the problem but the link only answer is still  breakable. If you where to provide detail on how to solve the problem in easy to use steps and use the link as 'where info came from' or for more detail if they are interested. The 'enter image description here' is good and shows an the area they would use. Please continue to answer questions but take a couple of minutes and read:- http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Comment: This answer does not answer the question.The Volume-Adjust-Icon does not display on ALL monitors after following your answer.