# How does one configure the Windows 10 Anniversary multiple monitor clock?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, taskbar, windows-10-v1607

Windows 10 has recently pushed its [Anniversary update](http://techreport.com/news/30029/windows-10-preview-build-14328-puts-clocks-on-every-taskbar) (version 1607) which now enables clocks on multiple monitors by default. This has solved a [major gripe](https://superuser.com/a/1108119/215646) from multi-monitor users who previously had to use third-party software in order to manage their multiple monitor taskbars.

However, a quick Google search doesn't turn up any configuration options for the clock. There is also no apparent option to show the notification area icons on both monitors.

How would one go about configuring the additional options in the updated Windows 10 taskbars?

Comment: I didn't have to enable anything on my machine.  If you create a new user, as a test, is the clock visible on both screens?  It turns out the reason I didn't have to enable it, is because I installed Windows with the 1607 .ISO, turns out an existing installation wouldn't have the feature enabled by default.

Comment: @Ramhound It is visible, I was wondering if I can configure it in any way.

Comment: I don't understand the question then.  What makes you think there are other configuration options?